# Postgres select on large (15m rows) table extremely slow, even with index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-performance

I'm trying to run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` but it simply won't finish because it's so slow. If it does, I'll post the results, but for now, here is the `EXPLAIN`.

Query:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT
    *
FROM
    "Posts" AS "Post"
WHERE
    (
        "Post"."featurePostOnDate" > '2020-06-25 19:28:07.816 +00:00'
        OR (
            "Post"."featurePostOnDate" IS NULL
            AND "Post"."userId" IN (6863684)
        )
    )
AND "Post"."private" IS NULL
ORDER BY
    "Post"."featurePostOnDate" DESC NULLS LAST,
    "Post"."createdAt" DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 10;
```

Result:

```
Limit  (cost=0.56..110.92 rows=10 width=1136)
  ->  Index Scan using posts_updated_following_feed_idx on "Posts" "Post"  (cost=0.56..284949.60 rows=25819 width=1136)
        Filter: (("featurePostOnDate" > '2020-06-25 19:28:07.816+00'::timestamp with time zone) OR (("featurePostOnDate" IS NULL) AND ("userId" = 6863684)))
```

Index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX  "posts_updated_following_feed_idx" ON "public"."Posts" USING btree (
    "featurePostOnDate" DESC NULLS LAST,
    "createdAt" DESC NULLS LAST
)
WHERE
    private IS NULL;
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** _not_ just a "simple" explain (as you already have)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Still waiting for the query to finish, but I think it's taking down the database server so it might never finish. I will update if it ever does but looking for any advice if that doesn't happen, as mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to write it as two separate queries, one for each branch of the OR.  Apply the limit to each query, then combine them and apply the limit again jointly.  But if the first branch finds ten rows, the second one doesn't need to run at all as all non-NULL dates already come first.

Comment: Rewriting the query is much more effort than adding an index at this point but I fear this solution might be best. I'll accept it because for other readers it's the way to go.

Comment: And then `UNION` the results together?

Answer (score 1):

So, as you are having 15m rows, and you have used `ANALYZE`. Using `ANALYZE` actually runs the query, you can refer it from here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-explain.html.

And in `WHERE` clause you have used the fields which are not indexed

```
WHERE
    (
        "Post"."featurePostOnDate" > '2020-06-25 19:28:07.816 +00:00'
        OR (
            "Post"."featurePostOnDate" IS NULL
            AND "Post"."userId" IN (6863684)
        )
    )
AND "Post"."private" IS NULL
```

So it is actually doing a sequential scan to filter out the rows

```
Filter: (("featurePostOnDate" > '2020-06-25 19:28:07.816+00'::timestamp with time zone) OR (("featurePostOnDate" IS NULL) AND ("userId" = 6863684)))
```

That might be the reason your query is slow.

***You might need compound indexes on*** `(featurePostOnDate, userId, private)` and `(featurePostOnDate, private)`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It took a while to build those compound indexes but neither of them worked. It still uses the index in OP.